# Software engineer intern or Software engineering intern?

Tags: software-industry, title, job-description

I see people use both in their job titles. Which one is correct?

Comment: Depends, which one does your company list as your actual job title?

Comment: I would say Software Engineer is who you are, and Software Engineering is what you do. I would use Software Engineer for a job title. Because you're asking the question I would assume it's ok to use Engineer in your title, but in some places you wouldn't be able to. In Canada, for example, an Engineer is a designation that requires specific study, training, and testing. You would instead just use Software Developer, Software Architect, etc.

Comment: @Marc I think the question here is only whether one should use "engineer" or "engineering" when it is combined with "Intern". In places that restrict the "engineer" title, I doubt you could get around that restriction by using "engineering" instead.

Comment: @Bradin - I agree that in places where engineer is restricted you wouldn't use either. Whether using Intern with the title or not, I would still say that a job title is who you are as opposed to what you do, so I would still say "Software Engineer, Intern" or "Intern Software Engineer". That said, I also agree with Philip in that in reality, nobody really cares. As a manager that does hiring, I wouldn't see Software Engineering Intern on a resume and see that as a negative.

Comment: @DavidK - The job title given by the company is in french and I couldn't find an english equivalent : It's is "Ingénieur études et developpement" which translates to "Studies and development engineer". I found that Software / Data engineer reflects more the work I am doing, and as Bradin stated the ambiguity in the question is about combining it with Intern since I am in an internship.

Comment: @YassinMarzouki You should mention the reason in your question. Then the answer should be different. For example, just leave the title as is, or use the literal translation (sounds fine). Changing it is a bit confusing, especially if you wrote "Software engineering Intern" but then I go checking and discover that your *actual* title was *Ingénieur études et developpement* which doesn't seem to match.

Comment: See also this thread for a similar question but about translating degree titles: [Having a degree in a non-english country, should I translate it to english in the cv?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10416/having-a-degree-in-a-non-english-country-should-i-translate-it-to-english-in-th)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both. Nobody cares.

So long as you're not massively misrepresenting what you did, the only point at which anyone is ever going to care about exactly what your job title was is if they are attempting to verify your work history, and even then they're not going to care about "engineer" vs "engineering". If you're still worrying about this, use whatever is listed on your contract.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a 'correct' as it could simply come down to preference, but I would choose the one that highlighted the engineer job title over the intern job title.

Do you want to be a software engineer who interned somewhere or a intern who did software engineering?